Syncfusion .NET Core Datepicker format validation is not working
<ejs-datepicker ejs-for="ToDate" StrictMode=true 
     style="background-color:#fff;" 
     min="01/01/2023" max="12/12/2023" 
     format="MM/dd/yyyy" id="ToDate"></ejs-datepicker>

The above Syncfusion datepicker in .NET Core is throwing an error.
Can you help?

It would really help if you told us WHAT ERROR you're getting .......

Some Javascript validation error on F12 Chrome Debugger Tools. I will get its details. Is it due to the issue that only EN-US formats are enabled by default for Syncfusion?

Since it's a SyncFusion component - why don't you ask SyncFusion support - they're the ones to know best ...

You need to utilize the min and max properties with actual date values rather than string formats. You can follow the Syncfusion DatePicker documentation to ensure smooth operation of the DatePicker component.
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";

    var minDate = new DateTime(2023, 1, 1);
    var maxDate = new DateTime(2023, 12, 12);
}

@model SyncfusionCoreWebApplication.Controllers.DatePicker

<div style="margin:150px auto;width:300px">
    <form method="post">
        <ejs-datepicker id="datepickerFor"
                        ejs-for="@Model.value"
                        strictMode="true"
                        min="@minDate"
                        max="@maxDate"
                        format="MM/dd/yyyy"></ejs-datepicker>
        <div id="errorMessage">
            <span asp-validation-for="value"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="submitbutton">
            <ejs-button id="submitButton" content="Submit"></ejs-button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

Ensure to refer to the following documentation for proper usage of the min and max properties, as well as rendering DatePickerFor:

min and max
properties

Render
DatePickerFor


Additionally, using the style attribute directly on the DatePicker isn't the correct method for customizing its appearance. For UI customization, refer to the following documentation:

Customizing DatePicker appearance

